# Recursively call post method in Node JS

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I want to call post method again if error is of duplicate key. Is there any workaround for this?
Id is auto generated using Math.Random().
If Error is of duplicate key i.e E11000 then the post method should be re-executed to generate a new id and store it in database.

```
const newRequestIndividualRouter = express.Router();
newRequestIndividualRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

newRequestIndividualRouter.route('/')
.post(checkAuth,(req,res,next) => { //POST METHOD
    req.body.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)+100000; //GENERATING ID
    NewRequestIndividual.create(req.body)
    .then((request) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
        res.json(request);
    },(err) => {
        
        if(err.code === 11000) {
            **** CALL POST METHOD AGAIN ****
        }
        next(err)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        next(err)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() is automatically seeded based on the current time

you need a good Pseudorandom number generator

try http://davidbau.com/seedrandom

Answer (score 0):

you can use uuid instead of Math.random().
link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid